# Local supabase instance can't create table due to a proxy error

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

When I start a supabase instance locally, it looks good in the terminal console, unfortunately when I try to add a new table, it throws error as:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charSet=\"utf-8\"/><title>Supabase</title><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"57x57\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"114x114\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"72x72\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"144x144\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"60x60\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"120x120\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"76x76\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"152x152\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png\"/><link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"/favicon/favicon-196x196.png\" sizes=\"196x196\"/><link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"/favicon/favicon-96x96.png\" sizes=\"96x96\"/><link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"/favicon/favicon-32x32.png\" sizes=\"32x32\"/><link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"/favicon/favicon-16x16.png\" sizes=\"16x16\"/><link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"/favicon/favicon-128.png\" sizes=\"128x128\"/><meta name=\"application-name\" content=\" \"/><meta name=\"msapplication-TileColor\" content=\"#1E1E1E\"/><meta name=\"msapplication-TileImage\" content=\"mstile-144x144.png\"/><meta name=\"msapplication-square70x70logo\" content=\"mstile-70x70.png\"/><meta name=\"msapplication-square150x150logo\" content=\"mstile-150x150.png\"/><meta name=\"msapplication-wide310x150logo\" content=\"mstile-310x150.png\"/><meta name=\"msapplication-square310x310logo\" content=\"mstile-310x310.png\"/><meta name=\"theme-color\" content=\"#1E1E1E\"/><link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"/favicon/favicon.ico\"/><link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"/favicon/favicon.ico\"/><link rel=\"manifest\" href=\"/favicon/site.webmanifest\" crossorigin=\"use-credentials\"/><link rel=\"alternate\" type=\"application/rss+xml\" href=\"/feed.xml\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon\" href=\"/favicon/favicon.ico\"/><meta name=\"msapplication-config\" content=\"/favicon/browserconfig.xml\"/><meta name=\"next-head-count\" content=\"30\"/><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" data-name=\"vs/editor/editor.main\" href=\"/monaco-editor/editor/editor.main.css\"/><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/css/fonts.css\"/><link rel=\"preload\" href=\"/_next/static/css/38c4032b1e652800.css\" as=\"style\" crossorigin=\"\"/><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/_next/static/css/38c4032b1e652800.css\" crossorigin=\"\" data-n-g=\"\"/><link rel=\"preload\" href=\"/_next/static/css/a7098dd4ec1d8475.css\" as=\"style\" crossorigin=\"\"/><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/_next/static/css/a7098dd4ec1d8475.css\" crossorigin=\"\"/><noscript data-n-css=\"\"></noscript><script defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\" nomodule=\"\" src=\"/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-c67a75d1b6f99dc8.js\"></script><script defer=\"\" src=\"/_next/static/chunks/7795-edb38dd65c5c397c.js\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script defer=\"\" src=\"/_next/static/chunks/1213-b37e19cb3abb9e02.js\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script defer=\"\" src=\"/_next/static/chunks/7606-e9485b6e77ee4596.js\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script defer=\"\" src=\"/_next/static/chunks/1788.e88386d24da58c19.js\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script defer=\"\" src=\"/_next/static/chunks/6629-e39cc28410ca60a6.js\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script defer=\"\" src=\"/_next/static/chunks/9729.fa1cfee2fe7c6b0a.js\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/chunks/webpack-0429d5a20246b5bf.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/chunks/framework-989c9c8f728099b7.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/chunks/main-3c777cdbc22097e7.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-4b63beca75a8f075.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/chunks/9619-81a15cddb19c9d8a.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/chunks/pages/404-70dbe3b4d69bb929.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/RBL1was47gZquM_7-lCdb/_buildManifest.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/RBL1was47gZquM_7-lCdb/_ssgManifest.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script></head><body><div id=\"__next\"><script>!function(){try{var d=document.documentElement,c=d.classList;c.remove('light','dark');var e=localStorage.getItem('theme');if('system'===e||(!e&&true)){var t='(prefers-color-scheme: dark)',m=window.matchMedia(t);if(m.media!==t||m.matches){d.style.colorScheme = 'dark';c.add('dark')}else{d.style.colorScheme = 'light';c.add('light')}}else if(e){c.add(e|| '')}if(e==='light'||e==='dark')d.style.colorScheme=e}catch(e){}}()</script><div class=\"min-h-full flex flex-col\"><div class=\"relative mx-auto flex h-screen w-full flex-col items-center justify-center\"><div class=\"absolute top-0 mx-auto w-full max-w-7xl px-8 pt-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8\"><nav class=\"relative flex items-center justify-between sm:h-10\"><div class=\"flex flex-shrink-0 flex-grow items-center lg:flex-grow-0\"><div class=\"flex w-full items-center justify-between md:w-auto\"><a href=\"/projects\"><span style=\"box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;width:initial;height:initial;background:none;opacity:1;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;max-width:100%\"><span style=\"box-sizing:border-box;display:block;width:initial;height:initial;background:none;opacity:1;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;max-width:100%\"><img style=\"display:block;max-width:100%;width:initial;height:initial;background:none;opacity:1;border:0;margin:0;padding:0\" alt=\"\" aria-hidden=\"true\" src=\"data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg%20xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27%20version=%271.1%27%20width=%27120%27%20height=%2724%27/%3e\"/></span><img alt=\"supabase\" src=\"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7\" decoding=\"async\" data-nimg=\"intrinsic\" style=\"position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%\"/><noscript><img alt=\"supabase\" loading=\"lazy\" decoding=\"async\" data-nimg=\"intrinsic\" style=\"position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%\" srcSet=\"/_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fsupabase-light.svg&amp;w=128&amp;q=75 1x, /_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fsupabase-light.svg&amp;w=256&amp;q=75 2x\" src=\"/_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fsupabase-light.svg&amp;w=256&amp;q=75\"/></noscript></span></a></div></div></nav></div><div class=\"absolute select-none opacity-[5%] filter transition duration-200 blur-none\"><h1 style=\"font-size:28rem\">404</h1></div><div class=\"flex flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-6 transition opacity-0\"><div class=\"flex w-[380px] flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-3 text-center\"><h3 class=\"text-xl\">Looking for something? </h3><p class=\"text-foreground-light\">We couldn&#x27;t find the page that you&#x27;re looking for!</p></div><div class=\"flex items-center space-x-4\"><a type=\"button\" class=\"relative justify-center cursor-pointer inline-flex items-center space-x-2 text-center font-regular ease-out duration-200 rounded-md outline-none transition-all outline-0 focus-visible:outline-4 focus-visible:outline-offset-1 border bg-brand-600 dark:bg-brand/70 hover:bg-brand-600/80 dark:hover:bg-brand text-white border-brand dark:border-brand focus-visible:outline-brand-600 shadow-sm text-sm leading-4 px-3 py-2\" href=\"/projects\"><span class=\"truncate\">Head back</span></a></div></div></div></div><div></div></div><script id=\"__NEXT_DATA__\" type=\"application/json\" crossorigin=\"\">{\"props\":{\"pageProps\":{}},\"page\":\"/404\",\"query\":{},\"buildId\":\"RBL1was47gZquM_7-lCdb\",\"nextExport\":true,\"autoExport\":true,\"isFallback\":false,\"dynamicIds\":[19729],\"scriptLoader\":[]}</script></body></html>",
        "requestId": "b7f0977d-d03c-4fdc-857f-835e15a2611e"
    },
    "message": "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charSet=\"utf-8\"/><title>Supabase</title><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"57x57\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"114x114\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"72x72\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"144x144\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"60x60\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"120x120\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"76x76\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon-precomposed\" sizes=\"152x152\" href=\"/favicon/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png\"/><link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"/favicon/favicon-196x196.png\" sizes=\"196x196\"/><link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"/favicon/favicon-96x96.png\" sizes=\"96x96\"/><link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"/favicon/favicon-32x32.png\" sizes=\"32x32\"/><link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"/favicon/favicon-16x16.png\" sizes=\"16x16\"/><link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"/favicon/favicon-128.png\" sizes=\"128x128\"/><meta name=\"application-name\" content=\" \"/><meta name=\"msapplication-TileColor\" content=\"#1E1E1E\"/><meta name=\"msapplication-TileImage\" content=\"mstile-144x144.png\"/><meta name=\"msapplication-square70x70logo\" content=\"mstile-70x70.png\"/><meta name=\"msapplication-square150x150logo\" content=\"mstile-150x150.png\"/><meta name=\"msapplication-wide310x150logo\" content=\"mstile-310x150.png\"/><meta name=\"msapplication-square310x310logo\" content=\"mstile-310x310.png\"/><meta name=\"theme-color\" content=\"#1E1E1E\"/><link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"/favicon/favicon.ico\"/><link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"/favicon/favicon.ico\"/><link rel=\"manifest\" href=\"/favicon/site.webmanifest\" crossorigin=\"use-credentials\"/><link rel=\"alternate\" type=\"application/rss+xml\" href=\"/feed.xml\"/><link rel=\"apple-touch-icon\" href=\"/favicon/favicon.ico\"/><meta name=\"msapplication-config\" content=\"/favicon/browserconfig.xml\"/><meta name=\"next-head-count\" content=\"30\"/><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" data-name=\"vs/editor/editor.main\" href=\"/monaco-editor/editor/editor.main.css\"/><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/css/fonts.css\"/><link rel=\"preload\" href=\"/_next/static/css/38c4032b1e652800.css\" as=\"style\" crossorigin=\"\"/><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/_next/static/css/38c4032b1e652800.css\" crossorigin=\"\" data-n-g=\"\"/><link rel=\"preload\" href=\"/_next/static/css/a7098dd4ec1d8475.css\" as=\"style\" crossorigin=\"\"/><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/_next/static/css/a7098dd4ec1d8475.css\" crossorigin=\"\"/><noscript data-n-css=\"\"></noscript><script defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\" nomodule=\"\" src=\"/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-c67a75d1b6f99dc8.js\"></script><script defer=\"\" src=\"/_next/static/chunks/7795-edb38dd65c5c397c.js\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script defer=\"\" src=\"/_next/static/chunks/1213-b37e19cb3abb9e02.js\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script defer=\"\" src=\"/_next/static/chunks/7606-e9485b6e77ee4596.js\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script defer=\"\" src=\"/_next/static/chunks/1788.e88386d24da58c19.js\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script defer=\"\" src=\"/_next/static/chunks/6629-e39cc28410ca60a6.js\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script defer=\"\" src=\"/_next/static/chunks/9729.fa1cfee2fe7c6b0a.js\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/chunks/webpack-0429d5a20246b5bf.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/chunks/framework-989c9c8f728099b7.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/chunks/main-3c777cdbc22097e7.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-4b63beca75a8f075.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/chunks/9619-81a15cddb19c9d8a.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/chunks/pages/404-70dbe3b4d69bb929.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/RBL1was47gZquM_7-lCdb/_buildManifest.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script><script src=\"/_next/static/RBL1was47gZquM_7-lCdb/_ssgManifest.js\" defer=\"\" crossorigin=\"\"></script></head><body><div id=\"__next\"><script>!function(){try{var d=document.documentElement,c=d.classList;c.remove('light','dark');var e=localStorage.getItem('theme');if('system'===e||(!e&&true)){var t='(prefers-color-scheme: dark)',m=window.matchMedia(t);if(m.media!==t||m.matches){d.style.colorScheme = 'dark';c.add('dark')}else{d.style.colorScheme = 'light';c.add('light')}}else if(e){c.add(e|| '')}if(e==='light'||e==='dark')d.style.colorScheme=e}catch(e){}}()</script><div class=\"min-h-full flex flex-col\"><div class=\"relative mx-auto flex h-screen w-full flex-col items-center justify-center\"><div class=\"absolute top-0 mx-auto w-full max-w-7xl px-8 pt-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8\"><nav class=\"relative flex items-center justify-between sm:h-10\"><div class=\"flex flex-shrink-0 flex-grow items-center lg:flex-grow-0\"><div class=\"flex w-full items-center justify-between md:w-auto\"><a href=\"/projects\"><span style=\"box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;width:initial;height:initial;background:none;opacity:1;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;max-width:100%\"><span style=\"box-sizing:border-box;display:block;width:initial;height:initial;background:none;opacity:1;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;max-width:100%\"><img style=\"display:block;max-width:100%;width:initial;height:initial;background:none;opacity:1;border:0;margin:0;padding:0\" alt=\"\" aria-hidden=\"true\" src=\"data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg%20xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27%20version=%271.1%27%20width=%27120%27%20height=%2724%27/%3e\"/></span><img alt=\"supabase\" src=\"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7\" decoding=\"async\" data-nimg=\"intrinsic\" style=\"position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%\"/><noscript><img alt=\"supabase\" loading=\"lazy\" decoding=\"async\" data-nimg=\"intrinsic\" style=\"position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%\" srcSet=\"/_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fsupabase-light.svg&amp;w=128&amp;q=75 1x, /_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fsupabase-light.svg&amp;w=256&amp;q=75 2x\" src=\"/_next/image?url=%2Fimg%2Fsupabase-light.svg&amp;w=256&amp;q=75\"/></noscript></span></a></div></div></nav></div><div class=\"absolute select-none opacity-[5%] filter transition duration-200 blur-none\"><h1 style=\"font-size:28rem\">404</h1></div><div class=\"flex flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-6 transition opacity-0\"><div class=\"flex w-[380px] flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-3 text-center\"><h3 class=\"text-xl\">Looking for something? </h3><p class=\"text-foreground-light\">We couldn&#x27;t find the page that you&#x27;re looking for!</p></div><div class=\"flex items-center space-x-4\"><a type=\"button\" class=\"relative justify-center cursor-pointer inline-flex items-center space-x-2 text-center font-regular ease-out duration-200 rounded-md outline-none transition-all outline-0 focus-visible:outline-4 focus-visible:outline-offset-1 border bg-brand-600 dark:bg-brand/70 hover:bg-brand-600/80 dark:hover:bg-brand text-white border-brand dark:border-brand focus-visible:outline-brand-600 shadow-sm text-sm leading-4 px-3 py-2\" href=\"/projects\"><span class=\"truncate\">Head back</span></a></div></div></div></div><div></div></div><script id=\"__NEXT_DATA__\" type=\"application/json\" crossorigin=\"\">{\"props\":{\"pageProps\":{}},\"page\":\"/404\",\"query\":{},\"buildId\":\"RBL1was47gZquM_7-lCdb\",\"nextExport\":true,\"autoExport\":true,\"isFallback\":false,\"dynamicIds\":[19729],\"scriptLoader\":[]}</script></body></html>"
}
```

[image]

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: Is this happening on the latest version of the Supabase CLI?

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue. I have even installed Supabase CLI on a separate clean machine - the same issue there as well. Look like a bug in Supabase Studio image.
And in terminal when the health of the packages was checked the studio was marked as "Service not healthy".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have gave it up since my environment is clean and I don't think the issue caused by it.